# ffmpeg: preserve timestamps when capturing from alsa/madi to mpeg-ts

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

Is it possible to preserve the original timestamps when caputuring from an ALSA/MADI input (which contain timestamps) when encoding to mpeg-ts/aac?
The MADI source is being delivered to us by 3rd party.

FFMpeg version: 4.2.2

At first, it seemed like an easy task, but I cannot get it to work correctly. The source presents an epoch timestamp (first line shows current timestamp from system as reference):

```
$ date +%s && ffprobe -show_entries stream -f alsa -i RME-5556
1589812196
ffprobe version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/software/ffmpeg-4.2.2-aeef8c6f --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libxvid --enable-libfdk_aac --disable-crystalhd --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-bzlib --extra-cflags=-I/compile/lame-3.100-4190d36b/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/faad2-2.8.8-0a416c66/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/faac-1.29.9.2-d0f85fb8/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/xvidcore-1.3.7-b5c2cdca/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/libogg-1.3.4-de57aa91/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/libtheora-1.1.1-7256273f/include --extra-cflags=-I/compile/alsa-lib-1.2.1.2-babf7811/include --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/lame-3.100-4190d36b/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/faad2-2.8.8-0a416c66/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/faac-1.29.9.2-d0f85fb8/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/xvidcore-1.3.7-b5c2cdca/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/libogg-1.3.4-de57aa91/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/libtheora-1.1.1-7256273f/lib --extra-ldflags=-L/compile/alsa-lib-1.2.1.2-babf7811/lib --enable-rpath --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-ldflags=-lpthread --extra-ldflags=-lm
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, alsa, from 'RME-5556':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1589812196.319736, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=pcm_s16le
codec_long_name=PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
sample_fmt=s16
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=unknown
bits_per_sample=16
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/1000000
start_pts=1589812196319736
start_time=1589812196.319736
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=1536000
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
```

But when encoding with the following command, a "strange" start_time is shown.

encoding a few frames:

```
$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -v verbose -f alsa -y -i RME-5556 -copyts -acodec aac -ar 48000 -b:a 256k -ac 2 -frames 100 -f mpegts -mpegts_copyts 1 test.ts
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'RME-5556':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1589813372.332589, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Applying unspecific -frames to non video streams, maybe you meant -vframes ?
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x3c5e040] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:s16 samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x3c5e400] auto-inserting filter 'auto_resampler_0' between the filter 'Parsed_anull_0' and the filter 'format_out_0_0'
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x3c61680] ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:48000Hz -> ch:2 chl:stereo fmt:fltp r:48000Hz
[mpegts @ 0x3c52500] frame size not set
[mpegts @ 0x3c52500] muxrate VBR, pcr every 9 pkts, sdt every 200, pat/pmt every 40 pkts
Output #0, mpegts, to 'test.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1024, 256 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
No more output streams to write to, finishing.  0.0kbits/s speed=7.84e+08x    
size=      76kB time=441614:49:34.45 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=7.43e+08x    
video:0kB audio:66kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 14.145925%
Input file #0 (RME-5556):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 101 packets read (413696 bytes); 101 frames decoded (103424 samples); 
  Total: 101 packets (413696 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (test.ts):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 101 frames encoded (103424 samples); 100 packets muxed (67857 bytes); 
  Total: 100 packets (67857 bytes) muxed
[AVIOContext @ 0x3c4eac0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 1 writeouts
[aac @ 0x3c53980] Qavg: 197.511
```

Analyzing it:

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner -loglevel warning -show_entries program test.ts 
[PROGRAM]
program_id=1
program_num=1
nb_streams=1
pmt_pid=4096
pcr_pid=256
start_pts=7366767433
start_time=7366.767433
end_pts=7368906744
end_time=7368.906744
TAG:service_name=Service01
TAG:service_provider=FFmpeg
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=[15][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x000f
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=0x100
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=663009069
start_time=7366.767433
duration_ts=192538
duration=2.139311
bit_rate=262125
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
...
[/STREAM]
[/PROGRAM]
```

So `start_pts` is set, but at an strange value. What could be wrong here?

What I tried and noticed:

- When encoding, the correct timetamp is shown on the input when `-copyts` has been defined (441614:49:34.45 in the above output)
- The `time_base` differs: `time_base=1/1000000` on input, `time_base=1/90000` on the output file. Could that be an issue?
- `-mpegts_copyts 1` seemed the option I was looking for, but doesn't seem to do anything.
- I tried many options like experimenting with `-af setpts=`, `-copytb`, and `-enc_time_base`, but without any luck.

Since it seems like the timestamp is off with some factor, it might be related to a time_base value or some sort? I tried to alter the reported `time_base=1/90000` using `enc_time_base` or `copytb` but that won't work (so I probably misunderstood that)

Am I missing something?

Thanks for any hints or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input timestamps from ALSA are 64-bit whereas MPEG-TS stores timestamps as 33-bit (there are extra bits available for greater precision but not range).

So, in your encoding run, the initial time is `1589813372.332589` which represents a PTS of `1589813372332589`. Converted to a time base of 90000, that's ~`143083203509933` but with a 33-bit width, the remainder is kept which is `663010989`. The difference from your actual starting PTS is due to the AAC priming sample, added by the encoder, and discarded after decoding.

Comment: I have to admit I have to figure out what you are saying exactly (will try to do that). I get the difference in bitsize and that the pts integer will not fit in 33bit.
But are you saying it just can't be done? Or is there some way to do any conversion?

Comment: The ALSA timestamps are a greater bit depth than MPEG-TS, so can't be stored as-is.

Comment: Thanks Gyan, that makes sense. Thank you for explaining this to me. Perhaps mpeg-ts is not the right container for this, i will ook into alternatives.